# Multiple choice exam with solution stencil

Tags: exam, examdesign, auto-multiple-choice, mcexam

I am looking for a package, that can create multiple choice exams with a solution stencil. That means there is an additional sheet created with an alignment mark and crosses for the correct answers. The mark on the solution stencil is then aligned with the mark on the exam sheets and it is immediately visible, which answers are correct.

The questions would have to be aligned vertically and the order optimized somehow.

This is used for the theoretical exam for the driving licence in Germany. The picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xu1rb.jpg) shows a solution stencil, the blue mark has to be aligned with the exam sheet.

We need this for a test immediately before a practical laboratory course to test whether the candidates have prepared enough to take part in the course.

If there is no latex way, I would be also happy for any other solution.

[image: Driving licence solution stencil]

Comment: https://jonathanchang.org/blog/painless-almost-multiple-choice-exams-in-latex/ ?

Comment: Or better, https://www.auto-multiple-choice.net/ is really powerful. We use it quite a bit...

Comment: I've checked both of them, they can do answer keys (a table with the questions and corresponding solution for different variants), but I didn't find any option to create a stencil (or template, vignette). With that stencil you don't have to match the question number with the solution manually, just move the stencil to the right position and wrong questions are directly apparent.